# Class level custom validation ASP MVC with Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, custom-attributes

I have the following attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class EnsureDeliveryRegistered: ValidationAttribute
{
    public EnsureDeliveryRegistered() { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null &&
        value is DeliveryViewModel &&
        IntranetOnlineForms.Util.Util.GetDeliveryCount((DeliveryViewModel)value) > 0;
    }
}
```

applied to the following class

```
[EnsureDeliveryRegistered(ErrorMessage = "Defined delivery date(s) result in 0 deliveries to register. Make sure you have the right date; if delivery is a recurring one make sure selected dates and days of week / period will match at least one delivery.")]
    public class DeliveryViewModel
{ //class here }
```

and I have property of this type in my page view model

```
public class RegisterDeliveryPage
{
    public RegisterDeliveryPage()
    {
        Delivery = new DeliveryViewModel();         
    }

    [Required]
    public DeliveryViewModel Delivery { get; set; }

    //the rest of the code
}
```

When I submit the page, whole RegisterDeliveryPage model is posted

```
[Route("register")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterNewDelivery(RegisterDeliveryPage model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //todo
            }

            return View("Register", model);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

        }
    }
```

After I check if ModelState, I can see that there's key "Delivery" with error message as specified in annotated attribute, but when I want to show it in view, it doesn't show up.

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("Delivery")
```

I have this same setup in another attribute, and really have no idea what's going wrong here.

Comment: You should add that custom validation to ModelState.AddModelError or use IValidatableObject to handle it automatically

Comment: I see it in list of key related model errors, it's just a matter of showing it in view...

Comment: try @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) in your cshtml

Comment: Have you given `Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Delivery)` a try?